# the dimension of the kernel of a linear transformation is equal to the dimension the kernel of its transpose: is it always true?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional subspaces, 
let $T: V$$\to$$W$ be a linear transformation, 
let $T*:W*$$\to$$V*$ be its transpose, 
prove that $dimKerT=dimKerT*$.

I can prove they have the same rank and I know it's true if T has a square matrix, but what if it doesn't? 
or if it *has* to be square, how do I prove it?

Comment: This is false as stated. If $T$ is surjective, then $T^*$ is injective. Therefore the kernel of $T^*$ is trivial, but the dimension of the kernel of $T$ can be as high as you want. For example, if $T$ is the projection $T:(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto x_1$ then the kernel of $T$ has dimension $n-1$. But $T^*$ is a non-zero mapping from $(\Bbb{R}^1)^*$ to $(\Bbb{R}^n)^*$, hence its kernel is $0$-dimensional.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen "if $T$ is surjective then $T^*$ is injective" why?

Comment: If $f\in W^*$ is non-zero, then $f(x)\neq0$ for some $x\in W$. Because $T$ is surjective, we can find $y\in V$ such that $x=T(y)$. Therefore $f(T(y))\neq0$ implying that $T^*(f)=f\circ T\neq0$. Hence the kernel of $T^*$ is trivial.

Comment: This is true if and only if $T$ is square.  This is just the fact that $T$ and $T^*$ necessarily have the same rank plus the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: @user735782 also, another perspective on surjectivity/injectivity: it suffices to note that $T$ is injective if and only if the columns of the associated matrix are linearly independent, and $T$ is surjective if and only if the rows of the associated matrix are linearly independent.